# live site and holding side by side until go live

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, dns, load-balancing

I will shortly be going live with a new .net web application. It will be deployed to a load balanced environment over 5 servers.

Before go live there is a holding site on all the 5 servers to which the domain is currently pointing -> www.website.com

Prior to go live, I would like to deploy the new site to 5 servers and for the holding site to remain and for it to be what the public sees.

And when the time comes, I can put the new site live with a flick of a switch. I also want the new site to be on the servers so that I can test it prior to go live.

I am running in IIS7.

This is common practice I presume so what is the easiest way doing that above and achieve installing the new site on the servers will not affecting the holding site. The new site be accessible to me but the holding site be viewed by the general public. Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: This question should most likely be posted on or moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create more than one website in IIS. I would create a new website on each machine with a temporary host header and then change it to the site URL when you want to go live. The load balancer may affect your decision on whether to deploy to another site using a host header, port, or some other identifier.